# New doesn't allocate memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator

I have this piece of code (in function `abc`)

```
matriz = new (nothrow) int*[qnt_objetos]; 
if (matriz == 0)
     exit(0);

for (int i = 0; i < qnt_objetos; i++)
{
    matriz[i] = new (nothrow) int[tam_mochila];
    if (matriz[i] == 0)
        exit(0);
}
```

`matriz` is an two-dimensional array declared as such (on main)

```
int **matriz = NULL;
```

However the memory space doesn't allocates when using the `new` operator. What I'm doing wrong? And also, is it better to allocate the memory directly in the `main` function? Doesn't that makes the code more illegible?

PS: Debugging it on NetBeans (or with the terminal) I got that `matriz` adress = `0x0` (`NULL` if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: Your code appears fine. What evidence do you have to support the idea that no memory is allocated?

Comment: I don't think `matriz` is a 2D array; it is a pointer to a pointer, which can be initialized with care so that `matrix[i][j]` works like a 2D array would work.

Answer (score 3):

This means the new operation is failed quietly (nothrow), and returning NULL, how much memory are you allocating?

Comment: when nothrow fails it doesn't return 0?

Answer (score 0):

I compiled and ran it with G++ in codeblocks. It ran just fine with out any issues. 
You should provide some error checking to make sure that the allocators have a proper value that isn't ridiculously large (IE: an unsigned long that received a -1).
 So be sure to check how big the buffer is going to be.

Comment: did you put the allocation on a function different from the declaration of matriz?

Comment: I just did `int **matriz = 0;` and set `int qnt_objetos = 15;` and `int tam_mochila = 6;` for my test purposes.